# Refused to get unsafe header “x-parse-job-status-id” - Vue.js and Parse Server

Tags: heroku, vue.js, parse-server

After months of working without any trouble, now when trying to make login, this error appears. The code shown is simplified, when it arrives at "Parse.User.logIn" is when the error happens. There are some similar questions here, but all of them are related to CORS, it runs proper on local server, but as we host it does not return data and display error in console as :

```
`    Clud-Code>
  Parse.Cloud.define("allUser", function (req, res) {

  var maxLevel, maxSponsor, topUser;
  var max = [];
  var topUserCount = 0;
 var lastPayOut = [];
var connector = [];
  var dataUT = [];
  let UserTrack = Parse.Object.extend("UserTrack");
   let UserDetails = Parse.Object.extend("UserDetails");

  let Scheme = Parse.Object.extend("Scheme");
  let SchemeRule = Parse.Object.extend("SchemeRule");
 let qS = new Parse.Query(Scheme);

  qS.equalTo("status", true);
     qS.first().then((qSresult) => {
    var currentScheme = new Scheme();
   currentScheme.id = qSresult.id;
    let qSR = new Parse.Query(SchemeRule);
       qSR.equalTo("scheme", currentScheme);
              qSR.find().then((qSRresult) => {
            for (let sr = qSRresult.length; sr <= qSRresult.length; sr++) {
              maxLevel = qSRresult[sr - 1].get("level");
                // maxTeam=qSRresult[sr].get("teamCount");
               maxSponsor = qSRresult[sr - 1].get("sponsorCount");
                 // var maxAmount=qSRresult[sr].get("level");
                }
           let obj = {
            maxLevel,
                maxSponsor
              }
                  max.push(obj);
                 var level, team, joinee, repurchase, active;
               let qUT = new Parse.Query(UserTrack);
  qUT.descending("createdAt")
             qUT.find().then((qUTresult) => {
                 for (let i of qUTresult) {
                     level = i.get("level");
                    team = i.get("team");
                    joinee = i.get("sponsored");
                 repurchase = i.get("repurchase");
                    active = i.get("Active");
                  //top user logic
                     if ((level < max[0].maxLevel) && (joinee >= 
                       max[0].maxSponsor)) {
        topUserCount = topUserCount + 1;
      }
      let obj = {
        id: i.get("user").id,
        date: i.get("createdAt"),
        level: level,
        // connector:qUDresult.get("connector").id,
        team: team,
        joinee: joinee,
        repurchase: repurchase,
        //   lastPayOut:lastPayOut,
        active: active
      }
      dataUT.push(obj);
      topUser = topUserCount;
    }
  }).then(() => {
    let qUD = new Parse.Query(UserDetails);
    qUD.descending("createdAt");
    qUD.find().then((qUDresult) => {
      for (let l = 0; l <= qUDresult.length - 1; l++) {

        let connectorU = qUDresult[l].get("connector").id;
        let uId = qUDresult[l].get("user").id;
        let objc = {

          connector: connectorU,
          uId: uId,
          id: dataUT[l].id,
          date: dataUT[l].date,
          level: dataUT[l].level,
          team: dataUT[l].team,
          joinee: dataUT[l].joinee,
          repurchase: dataUT[l].repurchase,
          active: dataUT[l].active
        }
        connector.push(objc);
      }
      //totalUser
      var totalUser = connector.length;
      var data = [connector, totalUser, topUser];
      console.log(data);
      res.success(data);

    })
  })

  })
})
})


clien-side code->
Parse.User.logIn("ac0427d", "abcd1234");
 Parse.Cloud.run('allUser', {

 }).then((result) => {
 console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
 });
`
```

Comment: Which domains are you using to access the application? (both locally and when running on Heroku). `localhost` is excluded from CORS checks by browsers so it's likely that whichever domain you are using has introduced a change to the CORS policy somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using a new version of the SDK (2.0.0), which contains many breaking changes compared to 1.x, without knowing it.

There are two possibilities to resolve the issue:

- Use parse-server 2.8.3 which was published yesterday
- Use the proper SDK version (see [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/622)) by pointing your parse SDK version to: the 1.11.1 (https://unpkg.com/parse@1.11.1/dist/parse.js)